# Get address of clicked Shape

Tags: excel, vba, range, shapes

I'm seeking a way to get a **clicked shape's address** (position/location) on it's spreadsheet.

In other words, I want to get the address of the shape which is clicked on the worksheet.

I'm using this code to find out the **clicked shape's Name** & **ID** and it's working fine:

```
Dim CallingShapeName As Variant

Dim CallingShapeID As Variant

CallingShapeName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name

Debug.Print CallingShapeName

CallingShapeID = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ID

Debug.Print CallingShapeID
```

But when I try to get the **clicked shape's address** with this code it isn't working:

```
Dim ShapeAddress As Range

Set ShapeAddress = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address)

Debug.Print ShapeAddress
```

Comment: `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address`

Comment: You might also want to assign the clicked shape to a variable and then access its properties rather than writing out the name each time.

Comment: Thanks for your tips SJR. I will assign a variable for it, it would most certaintly facilitate. But one question though. When I try to ```set ShapeAddress= ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address``` I get Run-time error '424' Object required. What am I missing here?

Comment: I've added an answer to illustrate that it's a two stage process. `Address` returns a string so you are trying to assign a string to a shape (object) variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is assign the clicked shape to a variable and then you can access its properties using the variable, as in

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim s As Shape

'assign object variable to clicked shape
Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

'then access its properties
Debug.Print s.Name
Debug.Print s.TopLeftCell.Address
Debug.Print s.BottomRightCell.Address
'etc

End Sub
```

Comment: I've now been given an opportunity to test out your solution and it works very well., thanks a lot @SJR ! You also made me realize why my suggested code didn't work, the variabe for the clicked shape ```ShapeAddress``` needed to be declared ```as string``` because the ```TopLeftCell.Address``` is returned as a String Data Type. But will apply your approach because your code is easier to read and follow.